# Unable to Upload Images to GCS from Xcode

Tags: objective-c, google-app-engine, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, multipartform-data

I am using

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

to get selected "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage" , then I am just to compress and upload to GCS.

```
-(void) saveImage: (NSData *)imageData forImageName: (NSString *) imageName 
{

    id customerObj=[[[SSAppCache cache]getObject:@"customerKey"].value JSONValue];

    NSString *requestURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",dbURL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

    NSString *imagePostUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/CustomerProfileService/uploadProfileImageAndUpdate", requestURL];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email": [customerObj valueForKeyPath:@"emailId"] , @"custId":[customerObj valueForKeyPath:@"customerId"]};

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:imagePostUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    double compressionRatio = 1.0;
    NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(defaultImage,compressionRatio);
    while ([imgData length]>50000) {
        compressionRatio=compressionRatio*0.5;
        imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(defaultImage,compressionRatio);
    }
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:@"fileBytes" fileName:imageName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

}];
[request addValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
DLog(@"Request URL is:%@",request);
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    DLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    DLog(@"Error: %@ operation Response code:%ld" , error,(long)[operation.response statusCode]);
}];
op.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
}
```

I have java Service method as follows , via

```
      public String uploadProfileImageAndUpdate(String email,String custId ,byte[] fileBytes) throws Exception
    {
      ...
     String filepath = GoogleStorageUtil.uploadFile(fileBytes, "<BUCKET DETAILS>", "<FOLDER>"+fileName, "image/jpeg");

    }
```

But, Its not even getting hit..... :(

```
  public static String uploadUsingGcs(byte[] fileBytes,String bucketName,String      objectName,String mimeType)
   {
    String filePath = null;
    try
    {
        mLogger.info("into the method to upload file "+objectName+" to "+bucketName);
        filePath=GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_URL+"/"+bucketName+"/"+objectName;
        GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder().initialRetryDelayMillis(10).retryMaxAttempts(10).totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000).build());
        GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(bucketName, objectName);
        GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().cacheControl("max-age=31557600").mimeType(mimeType).acl(ACL_PUBLIC_READ).build();
        GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename,options);
        writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(fileBytes));
        writeChannel.close();
        mLogger.info("File successfully uploaded");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        mLogger.warning("The error came becoz of "+e.getMessage());
        for(StackTraceElement s:e.getStackTrace()){
            mLogger.warning(s.toString());
        }
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

I am unable to upload images , I tried all type like Multipart , Json , String etc , Nothing working. No Error , Warning etc... Its calm :( My target ios version 7.0 above , I know some silly thing is an issue , help me find out that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the files are not uploaded or that maybe they don't have the expected permission and therefore not readable?  (I wonder if the bucket permission might have something
to do with the reading part).
Do you see anything in the App Engine application log associated with the upload request?
Is the value of ACL_PUBLIC_READ is "public-read"?
FYI, in your case, where all data is available, it would be better to write it this way:
gcsService.createOrReplace(filename,options, );

Comment: Yes I Checked all GCS Permission etc... I am able to upload images from Browser hit. But ,communication between app via web service is an issue. Multipart , Image Upload only the issue. :(